# Webkit not applying css margin-bottom

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, margin

Please see this page: http://goo.gl/U9cQl

In Firefox, the margin-bottom property is applied correctly to the Contact Us box, pushing it 50 pixels up from the bottom of the page.

This doesn't happen in Safari + Chrome and I can't work out why! Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, I turned off your rule for `html,body { height: 100%; }` and that fixed it for me.

Comment: That's done it, thanks very much! I always thought it was good practice to set the body height to 100%, is this not the case?

Comment: I know that used to be good advice, but I think these days it's unnecessary. normalize.css doesn't use that rule, and that's what I tend to use for a set of base styles.

Comment: @dai.hop if you don't need it, don't set it.  A `min-height: 100%` is generally only necessary for things like *sticky footers*, where a short page will prevent it from being attached to the bottom of the viewport.